# Trying to pick from 3 options in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a large spreadsheet that contains some pricing information.  Column B has one price plan, column C has a 2nd plan, if both of those are blank default to Column A.  Column A always has a value for each record, If B has a value C will be blank, If C has a value B will be blank.  I need to first check to see if B or C has a value, if both are blank use A.  e.g

```
A1 $15.00  B1 12.00  C1 ""
A2 $18.00  B2 ""     C2 $17.50
A3 $25.00  B3 ""     C3 ""
```

In row 1 I want to choose $12.00  In row 2 I want to choose $17.50 in row 3 I want to default to $25.00

I am really struggling to figure this out using nested if statements.  I can get it to choose B or C, but not default to A if B and C are blank.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Gene

Comment: Improving your formatting will allow others to help answer your questions.  Note that you can get "formatted" code-like text by using the "Code" button in the visual editor, or by indenting the line four spaces.  I've made an edit to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much Cale.  I really appreciate the help!  Now if I can just figure out the formula..... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=IF(SUM(B1:C1)=0,A1,SUM(B1:C1))
```

This checks whether B1 and C1 are both empty (by adding them together and checking whether  the total is zero) and [IF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function) TRUE returns the value in A1, if FALSE the sum of the B1 and C1 cells (with one or other assumed always to be zero).

Depending on what other data you have:

```
=MIN(A1:C1)
```

may be shorter and as effective (assumes the default value in Column A is always more than the B or C value).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  So simple!  I really do appreciate it.